# Phonegap Video player plugin for iOS

Tags: ios, video, cordova, stream, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I play Youtube videos using the phonegap-videoplayer-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654943/how-do-i-play-youtube-videos-using-the-phonegap-videoplayer-plugin)

I am new to iOS development.
I'm developing an phonegap based iOS app in which I have to stream a video 
without browser(in the device player).

My app has to stream a lot of videos based on URL

Edit: This [link](https://github.com/eiffelqiu/phonegap-videoplayer-plugin) is useful. Its working fine, but needs direct link to videos, like
http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4

Youtube videos are not yet working. Can anyone suggest the solution