# How do I play Youtube videos using the phonegap-videoplayer-plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, youtube, video-streaming

I am using [a Phonegap plugin for playing a video](https://github.com/eiffelqiu/phonegap-videoplayer-plugin) in my iOS app. I'm able to play a video with the URL format like `http://easyhtml5video.com/images/happyfit2.mp4`.

How do I play Youtube videos using the phonegap-videoplayer-plugin?

Comment: Could you just use the iframe code that's available on youtube.com?

Comment: iframe is useful, but in case of ios autoplay is a trouble as the flash content is not directly supported

Comment: The iframe will degrade to html5 player in such cases

Comment: iFrame will show a random thumbnail, which is not preferable in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some methods that will give you direct link to youtube videos. Use ["gdata"](http://google-code-updates.blogspot.in/2007/08/youtube-now-with-gdata-goodness.html) option to find all possible video formats.

Then parse the result to get desired link. Hope this might be useful

Answer (score 2):

> [YouTube Terms of Service](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms): "You agree not to access Content
>   through any technology or means other than the video playback pages of
>   the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other explicitly
>   authorized means YouTube may designate."

Comment: I completely accept it, but I'm looking at the source link of the video so that it can be directly accessed by the player.

Answer (score 1):

> But everywhere I found the code to be edited in .m and .h files. None have explained how to use it.

That's because you can only directly use MPMoviePlayerController from native apps (written in Objective-C). For any other technology you'll have to have an intermediary layer in between.

From googling, I found [this plugin](https://github.com/eiffelqiu/phonegap-videoplayer-plugin) for PhoneGap that claims to integrate with MPMoviePlayerController. I've no idea if it's any good, but it might do as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I'm trying it now. Will update the results here.

Comment: Thanks, its working fine... Will explore it. You saved my time. I have been strugging for it wholw day

Answer (score 1):

try to give the youtube url in this format.

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/jxXukpxNSx4
```

You will get the desired result. But Autoplay is not enabled, as Apple stopped supporting autoplay to save user's bandwidth